# Why the hosted website is not working by using ip address but working is used the localhost?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms, windows-server-2012

I am facing a very peculiar issue.

On `IIS 10` in windows server I have added a website to `IIS` and in binding, I assigned it an IP address and port numbers like `172.24.26.244` and `9099`. Also, added an inbound rule for it in the firewall (even disabled it).

Now, upon browsing in that system (server), it works if I use 
`http://localhost:9099/index.aspx`. It works overall but if I use `http://172.24.26.244:9099/index.aspx` then it doesn't work i.e. login and not even throw an error.

I have done everything as I have mentioned. I have put it in `inetpub/wwwroot` directory but still, it doesn't work on ip address, even the IP address is getting pinged and is the working ip address of the system.

It goes to the index page but doesn't log in and doesn't even throw an error.

Why?

Code:

This is the login code:

```
Private Sub cmdLoginLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles cmdLogin.Click
        Dim l_strRedirect As String
        Dim l_strAuthTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket
        Dim l_strEncryptedTicket As String
        Dim l_objhashedDataBytes As Byte()
        Dim l_strAuthCookie As HttpCookie
        Dim l_blnTransfer As Boolean = False
        Dim l_strUserID, l_strPassword, l_strHashedPwd As String
        Dim l_intCount As Integer
        Dim v_objDSLic As New DataSet
        lblErrMsg.Text = ""
        Try

            ' GetChangeConnectionString()
            v_ObjBREngine = New BusniessRule.DataAccess
            t_objUtil = New Utility

            Try
                v_ObjBREngine.SetCon(v_strConnString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'lblErrMsg.Text = "DataBase Name or Path is incorrect"
                Throw New Exception("Database Name or Path is incorrect")
            End Try

            l_strUserID = Replace(txtUserName.Text, "'", "''")
            l_strPassword = Replace(txtPassword.Text, "'", "''")



            If l_strUserID <> "VELOSI" Then

                v_objDSLic = v_ObjBREngine.FetchSqlDS("select d from ddd")

                If v_objDSLic.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    Dim iString As String = v_objDSLic.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
                    Dim oDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(iString, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)

                    If DateTime.Now > oDate Then
                        lblErrMsg.Text = "Your license has been expired. Please renew your license."
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                End If
            End If
            '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            'Dim count As Integer = Application("ActiveSessionCount")

            'If count > 2 Then
            '    lblErrMsg.Text = "Only Two Person are allowed to login at a time."
            '    Exit Sub
            'End If

            If IsAuthenticated(l_strUserID, l_strPassword) Then
                'Create a new forms authentication ticket 
                l_strAuthTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, l_strUserID, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), False, v_strGroup)

                'To create an encrypted string representation of the ticket and store it as data within an HttpCookie object
                'Now encrypt the ticket
                l_strEncryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(l_strAuthTicket)
                'Create a cookie and add the encrypted ticket to the
                'cookie as data.
                l_strAuthCookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, l_strEncryptedTicket)

                'Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
                Response.Cookies.Add(l_strAuthCookie)

                'Redirect the user to the originally requested page
                l_strRedirect = Request("ReturnURL")
                If l_strRedirect <> "" Then
                    l_blnTransfer = True
                Else
                    If Session("UID") >= 1 Then
                        l_strRedirect = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Url") & "DashBoard_1.aspx"
                        l_blnTransfer = True
                    Else
                        l_strRedirect = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Url") & "frmInbox.aspx"
                        l_blnTransfer = True
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                t_objUtil.SetCookie("pocLang", "2")
                Throw New Exception("Invalid User ID or Password. (Err Code: 1001)")
            End If

            If chkbRemember.Checked Then
                t_objUtil.SetCookie("pocLang", "1")
                t_objUtil.SetCookie("UCrendentials", l_strUserID)
            Else
                t_objUtil.SetCookie("pocLang", "2")
                t_objUtil.SetCookie("UCrendentials", Nothing)
            End If
        Catch b_objEx As Exception
            l_blnTransfer = False
            lblErrMsg.Text = b_objEx.Message
        Finally
            v_ObjBREngine.Dispose()
            v_ObjBREngine = Nothing
            t_objUtil = Nothing
            If l_blnTransfer Then Response.Redirect(l_strRedirect, True)
        End Try
    End Sub
#End Region
```

Also, the AppSettings("Url") is getting picked from the web.config where we have also set the IP address with the port number.

And the interesting part is that even if i type `ip`, it still appears, i mean the `index` page but doesn't login and doesn't throw error. I was checking using remote desktop.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? Also have you made sure that up security is not tripping you up? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/? Have you bound the correct protocol(s)? You should give us pictures of your iis setup

Comment: Hi, I am using this on Internet Explorer as this is very old website and is only friendly on Internet Explorer. I have setup the website my whole career on different webservers but this one is not getting along with it i don't know why.

Comment: In IIS  it is type=http, hostname=empty, port=9099, ipaddress=172.24.26.244

Comment: Run a report and edit your question to include it, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: can you telnet to that port?

Comment: @CaiusJard: yes i can